# Unable to grep for the version from the output

Tags: text-processing, grep, search

I have a script that gives the below output:

```
WVER0010I: Copyright (c) IBM Corporation 2002, 2012; All rights reserved.
WVER0012I: VersionInfo reporter version 1.15.1.48, dated 2/8/12

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBM WebSphere Product Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report at date and time September 23, 2020 2:00:11 PM IST

Installation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product Directory        /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer
Version Directory        /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/version
DTD Directory            /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/version/dtd
Log Directory            /var/ibm/InstallationManager/logs

Product List
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IHS                      installed

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                  IBM HTTP Server for WebSphere Application Server
Version               8.5.5.10
ID                    IHS
Build Level           cf101629.01
Build Date            7/21/16
Package               com.ibm.websphere.IHS.v85_8.5.5010.20160721_0036
Architecture          x86-64 (64 bit)
Installed Features    IBM HTTP Server 64-bit with Java, Version 6
                      Core runtime

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to get the version on al flavors of OS like Aix, Linux and Solaris

With the below command I'm getting the desired output:

```
sh /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/versionInfo.sh | grep -A 1 WebSphere | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Output: 8.5.5.10

However, when the script output changes slightly like below the same command does not get me the version.

```
WVER0010I: Copyright (c) IBM Corporation 2002, 2005, 2008; All rights reserved.
WVER0012I: VersionInfo reporter version 1.15.5.1, dated 6/15/11

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBM WebSphere Application Server Product Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report at date and time September 23, 2020 1:54:10 PM GMT+05:30

Installation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product Directory        /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer
Version Directory        /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/version
DTD Directory            /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/version/dtd
Log Directory            /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer/logs
Backup Directory         /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer/properties/version/nif/backup
TMP Directory            /tmp

Product List
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IHS                      installed

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                     IBM HTTP Server
Version                  7.0.0.19
ID                       IHS
Build Level              cf191132.09
Build Date               8/13/11
Architecture             Intel (32 bit)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Output:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, the desired output is:

```
7.0.0.19
```

I 'm expecting the same command to give the version number for both the output above.

Note: I guess if we can search for the the line below the line starting with `"Name"` followed by `<whitespaces>` and then followed by `"IBM HTTP Server"` then we will get the version. However, I'm not able to get `grep` to get me the desired out.

Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest an `awk`-based solution if that tool is available to you:

```
awk '/^Installed Product/{f=1} f && $1=="Version" {print $2; f=0}'
```

will set a flag `f` once the "Installed Product" header was found, and (only) then look for a line starting with "Version". It will print the second of the whitespace-separated fields of that line, which is the version. As a safety measure, it will at the same time reset the flag to ensure no later occurence of a "Version" line generates false output.

You can use it as

```
sh /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/versionInfo.sh | awk '/^Installed Product/{f=1} f && $1=="Version" {print $2; f=0}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your example input, you are simply searching for the stretch of numbers and `.` that comes after the word `Version` on lines where `Version` is the first word of the line and where it is followed by whitespace and then a number. If you have GNU `grep`, you can simply do:

```
sh /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/versionInfo.sh | grep -oP '^Version\s+\K\d.*'
```

If you don't have GNU `grep`, you can use:

```
sh /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/versionInfo.sh | sed -n 's/^Version[ \t]*\([0-9]\)/\1/p'
```

Or, perhaps more legibly:

```
sh /ihs/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/versionInfo.sh | 
    awk '/^Version  *[0-9]/{print $2}'
```